# How to format date time picker?

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker, centering

I have this date time picker formatted like that using this code

```
#Region "date time picker"
            With .dtpDate1
                .Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
                .CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"

            End With
            With .dtpDate2
                .Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
                .CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
            End With
#End Region
```

[image]

The problem is I can't center the text `04/21/2016`.

**Question:** How do I center it?

Comment: You don't. The DTP doesn't support that.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an old thread and my solution is not the cleanest but this might help someone looking into this.

It works good for me when using static datetimepickers:

**Add the necessary amount of spaces to your custom format:**

```
.CustomFormat = "   MM/dd/yyyy"
```

[I found this trick in rv88's comment on Wednesday, June 7, 2017 5:12 PM here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SqlServer/en-US/20e6f539-95a4-46de-85f2-01de2438320a/datetimepicker-alignment-center?forum=winforms)